# Making sure that the table width of two tables are the same even though they don't have the same number of columns

Tags: html, css

I have two tables with different number of columns and their total width are different, and for some reason I can't fix it.

I tried changing the width of the tables, but it doesn't seem to work. Even when I set them both to 100%, the width of the table seems to depend on the number of columns.

https://jsfiddle.net/rp8yq1vu/

```html
<div style="background-color:black">
  <div style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
    <div>
      <table style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; table-layout: auto; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">
        <thead style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);">
          <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
            <th style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;"></th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;"></th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">1</th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">2</th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">3</th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">4</th>
            <th style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; overflow-wrap: break-word;">5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="height: inherit; overflow: hidden auto;">
      <table style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; table-layout: auto; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">
        <tbody style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
          <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
            <td style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;">1.</td>
            <td style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; font-weight: 900; overflow-wrap: break-word; line-height: 25px;">hello<br></td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
            <td style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;">1.</td>
            <td style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; font-weight: 900; overflow-wrap: break-word; line-height: 25px;">tforty<br></td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
            <td style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;">1.</td>
            <td style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; font-weight: 900; overflow-wrap: break-word; line-height: 25px;">attitude899<br></td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
            <td style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;">1.</td>
            <td style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; font-weight: 900; overflow-wrap: break-word; line-height: 25px;"><img src="https://www.broken.org" width="100" height="100"><br></td>
            <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want both tables to have the same width and hide the black background.

Comment: They are the same size.  Here is a fiddle with just the background color changed: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/nqL27jmc/

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: There's the background underneath the table header.

Comment: Any reason you dont want to make it one table? You could just move the `thead` from the first into the second table, would help you keep it all together from my point of view.

Comment: I am using a library to create the table. The above is a modified version of the html output.